# Cannot load Minecraft 1.13. Crashes immediately

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

Here is my crash report. Can anyone help?

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// Why is it breaking :(

Time: 7/23/18 9:11 AM
Description: Initializing game

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Failed to locate library: liblwjgl32.so
    at org.lwjgl.system.Library.loadSystem(Library.java:147)
    at org.lwjgl.system.Library.loadSystem(Library.java:67)
    at org.lwjgl.system.Library.<clinit>(Library.java:50)
    at org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil.<clinit>(MemoryUtil.java:61)
    at org.lwjgl.system.MemoryStack.<init>(MemoryStack.java:61)
    at org.lwjgl.system.MemoryStack.create(MemoryStack.java:82)
    at org.lwjgl.system.MemoryStack.create(MemoryStack.java:71)
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal$SuppliedThreadLocal.initialValue(ThreadLocal.java:284)
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal.setInitialValue(ThreadLocal.java:180)
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:170)
    at org.lwjgl.system.MemoryStack.stackGet(MemoryStack.java:628)
    at org.lwjgl.system.MemoryStack.stackPush(MemoryStack.java:637)
    at cfs.a(SourceFile:126)
    at cfi.an(SourceFile:554)
    at cfi.am(SourceFile:433)
    at cfi.a(SourceFile:377)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:144)


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Head --
Thread: Client thread
Stacktrace:
    at org.lwjgl.system.Library.loadSystem(Library.java:147)
    at org.lwjgl.system.Library.loadSystem(Library.java:67)
    at org.lwjgl.system.Library.<clinit>(Library.java:50)
    at org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil.<clinit>(MemoryUtil.java:61)
    at org.lwjgl.system.MemoryStack.<init>(MemoryStack.java:61)
    at org.lwjgl.system.MemoryStack.create(MemoryStack.java:82)
    at org.lwjgl.system.MemoryStack.create(MemoryStack.java:71)
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal$SuppliedThreadLocal.initialValue(ThreadLocal.java:284)
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal.setInitialValue(ThreadLocal.java:180)
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:170)
    at org.lwjgl.system.MemoryStack.stackGet(MemoryStack.java:628)
    at org.lwjgl.system.MemoryStack.stackPush(MemoryStack.java:637)
    at cfs.a(SourceFile:126)
    at cfi.an(SourceFile:554)
    at cfi.am(SourceFile:433)

-- Initialization --
Details:
Stacktrace:
    at cfi.a(SourceFile:377)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:144)

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.13
    Operating System: Linux (i386) version 4.13.0-46-generic
    Java Version: 1.8.0_171, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: OpenJDK Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 8350200 bytes (7 MB) / 174862336 bytes (166 MB) up to 523501568 bytes (499 MB)
    JVM Flags: 5 total; -Xmx512M -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -Xmn128M
    Launched Version: 1.13
    LWJGL: 3.1.6 build 14
    OpenGL: ~~ERROR~~ NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.lwjgl.system.Library
    GL Caps: 
    Using VBOs: Yes
    Is Modded: Probably not. Jar signature remains and client brand is untouched.
    Type: Client (map_client.txt)
    Resource Packs: 
    Current Language: ~~ERROR~~ NullPointerException: null
    Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
    CPU: <unknown>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I know how to fix it.. If you have recently made the world, go to your MC files and delete that world, but if that's not the case, try this: Go to your Task Manager, and close literally anything that has Minecraft in the name or is Minecraft related. If neither of those work, I don't know what else to say.

Answer (score 0):

The liblwjgl32.so library at the beginning of your error report is only for the 64 bit systems. Either upgrade your os and java to 64 bit version, or stay at 1.12.2 or earlier versions of Minecraft to keep playing on current configuration.